# htaccess RewriteEngine causing subdirectory issues

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hosting

Quick question for you guys. My website's basic file structure is as follows:

> > www.example.com
> >
> > /
> >
> > index.php
> >
> > otherFiles.php
> >
> > ./directory
> >
> > ```
> >    index.php
> > ```

Currently if you were to type in **example.com/directory** it would redirect to my 404 page. You have to type in **example.com/directory/index**. My assumption was that for every directory, the default page was `index` with either the `.php` or `.html` extension. I guess I was wrong, so I configured that directory's `.htaccess` as follows:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

But, no progress. Is there something I am missing? To clarify, I would like the url of **example.com/directory** to open the index file in that directory. Here is my universal `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

## Edit

So, I commented out the 3 `Rewrite` commands in my htaccess and now my issue is resolved. The problem is that now the php file extensions are showing. Is there a way to include rewrite rules without interfering with default index pages? Or is the problem somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the 404 is due to the *directory* `/directory.php` not existing. Because your `RewriteRule` is executed with the condition only that it isn't a real file (`%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`), the rule is mistakenly applied for directories, attempting to append `.php`. It's easily fixed with a `!-d`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Now, when a directory like `/directory` is requested, the default `DirectoryIndex` will be used and no rewrite will take place.

Comment: For some reason, this only works for the directory and one other root php file, the other pages are causing 404 errors

Comment: Nevermind, it just took a long time to update for some reason. Thanks!